# Secure input field against mySQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

I have made an edit form for my users, now when I update it needs to be secure against MySQL injection.

Right now I have this query

```
$sqledit = mysql_query("UPDATE **** SET titel = '$title', content = '$content' WHERE `ID` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']),mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txttitle'])) or die (mysql_error());
```

NOTE: $content is an ckeditor with has build in protection methods against MySQL injection?

Still when I put something like: ééáá",''øøí in txttitle it gives the following error.

mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Comment: I do recommend to use a ORM System. For PHP this could be Doctrine or Propel. These Systems allow much easier data persistence and usually provide methods against SQL-Injection.

Comment: Use prepared statements and an up to date mysql extension like `PDO` or `mysqli` the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and get removed with one of the next PHP versions.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the actual data, but with you giving a second parameter to the function that makes no sense.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER prepared statement is not a must.

Comment: No it's not but it's highly recommended.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER wrong concept; in fact it's the reverse. Prepared statement has negative impact on speed. Avoid using it unless you don't care about speed / optimization.

Comment: Yes but he has to deal with user input and for user input prepared statements are highly recommended imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Injection is not the cause of your error. However, you misuse the `mysql_query()` function. The signature is:

```
mysql_query ( string $query , resource $link_identifier = NULL )
```

but you provide a non-link-identifier in your 2nd parameter, which causes the error.

*Note: Stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.*

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, due to the many edits I copied the wrong query here. I will search some more information about mySQLi and PDO. Thank you!

Comment: if you find the answer useful, please accept the answer & upvote. thanks!